# Facing issues while installing mews/captcha in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, version, captcha

I have installed the latest PHP version on my device. I am trying to install `mews/captcha library` in my project but due to some version conflicts, I am failing to do so.

composer.json :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "mews/captcha": "~2.0"
},

"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

**This is the output in terminal: [image]**

I have tried commands -

> composer update

> composer install --ignore-platform-reqs

> composer require mews/captcha:*

All are not working

Comment: What the composer is saying is that dependencies of the new package go in conflict with the dependencies of the other packages.
Did you try to use composer require mews/captcha:* as composer itself is suggesting?

Comment: Can you share the chunk where the `illuminate/support` dependency is declared?

Comment: @ThomasSquall Yes I tried that as well

Comment: @LajosArpad so sorry but could you please tell me where will I find that.

Comment: It should be in composer.json. You are only sharing a part of it with us, but the error message suggests that there is some other dependency on the same resource which causes a version conflict.

Comment: Enabling the gd extension in xampp/php/php.ini and running  composer require mews/captcha:* worked for me